# Get position of Jira ticket within swimlane

Tags: php, api, jira

I'm using the Atlassian REST API to fetch data regarding Jira tickets.

PHP code (snippet):

```
$command  = "curl -u user@company.com:$apiToken -X GET -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \"https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="SC" AND status != "Done" AND status != "Closed"&maxResults=50&startAt=$startAt\"";
$json = @exec($command, $return_var);
```

How do I get the current position of a ticket within its column/swimlane of the kanban board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the tickets by `Rank`. Ideally using `ORDER BY Rank ASC` in your JQL.

This should return your issues in the order they are in the column.